# Creating an expression inside a single JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way where I can output the result by only 1 function, instead of two? I'm currently learning JavaScript, and I wanted to call a function using `document.write` instead of `getElementById` and this is what I've came across of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function addstrings(fname, lname) 
    { 
        var full; 

        full = fname + lname; 
        return  full; 
    } 

    function myfunction() 
    { 
        result = addstrings('Jerome', 'Smith'); 
        document.write (result); 
    } 
</script> 
</head>  
<body>
<script>
    myfunction(); 
</script>
```

Comment: `result = addstrings('Jerome', 'Smith');` can be just `result = 'Jerome Smith';`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Avoid `document.write` as much as possible.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to ask. You can put one function inside of the other or you can put the functionality of one function inside the other. In order to avoid downvotes in the future, you may want to spend some time in a beginner's community like freecodecamp.com before asking more questions here.

Comment: Why are there `head` and `body` and two script elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the refactored code and then I'll explain what's going on:

```
<head>
  <script>
    const addStrings = function (firstName, lastName) {
      return firstName + lastName;
    };

    const addStringsAlternate = (firstName, lastName) => firstName + lastName;
  </script> 
</head>
<body>  
<script>
  document.write(addStrings('Jerome', 'Smith'));
  document.write(addStringsAlternate('Jerome', 'Smith'));
</script>
```

So what's happening here?

1. Code style is important. Use descriptive variable names. Use camelCase. Use single quotes, not doubles. Use indentation. Most people prefer 2 spaces like me, others use 4 or tabs. Any is fine but use one consistently.
2. To directly answer your question, you can just call the `addStrings` function directly inside your `document.write` function. `addStrings()` returns your string to `document.write`, which then writes the string into the DOM.
3. Notice how I refactored your function `addStrings`.

There are 3 ways to declare a variable in js. `var`, `let`, and `const`. Especially since you are learning, I highly recommend to just stick with `let` and `const`. `var` will cause you problems that you don't need to go through right now. Generally speaking, `const` means "this variable will never be changeable in the future". `let` is like `var` and means "this variable can be reassigned later".

The reason `let` and `const` were added a few years ago is about variable scope, meaning where in your program can the variable be found. Without going too deep into the woods, `let` and `const` force your variables to only live in the scope they're declared. I recommend you googling for `let vs var` and `const vs var` and pay attention to the bits about scope.

Your original way of declaring `addStrings` totally works, but I wanted to show you some alternate ways. Basically, you can declare functions as regular variables and don't need the `function` key word. In the `addStringsAlternate` function, its using the "arrow function" declaration. When you get into learning about `this` (which relates to scoping), the arrow function will be your friend. There are edge cases where arrow functions can cause a problem, but we don't need to get into that now. Anyway, notice how in the arrow function I'm not using `return`. In arrow functions, if you are doing a simple operation you can just write the code write after the `=>` and the return is automatic.